# how to define broadcast receiver for android version more than 3.0?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

this is my phonestate class where im checking phone state change

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener 
{

  private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";

  Context context; //Context to make Toast if required 
  public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) 
  {
    super();
    this.context = context;
  }
  public void onCallStateChange(int state, String incomingNumber)
  {

        Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
        Log.v(TAG, incomingNumber);

        switch(state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "RINGING");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming number :"+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
        }        }
```

this is my broadcast receiver class where connecting with broadcast

```
    public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "CustomBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();

    telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);
}
```

i got some idea to define intent in java file,bcz android version
 more than 3.0 needs 
      to define intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction("com.example.SendBroadcast");
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
      sendBroadcast(intent);
```

i don't know how to and where to define this part of code whether in
 broadcast class or phonestate class.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously !! call this code into  CustomPhoneStateListener class other wise broadcast will never called.

Comment: Very sorry ,i couldn't understand properly,,,i need to put this in mainactivity class and to call in phonestatelistener or have to put this in phonestatelistener...... thanks for your reply ..

Comment: i tried this in mainactivity inside oncreate() and called in phonestatelistener MainActivity m=new MainActivity(); but still it is not working help me in this